# Setting UIImageView contentMode shows no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` which is sized to 366 x 375 (confirmed by `NSLog` statement) and a `UIImage` which is is sized to 400 x 600 (again confirmed with a log statement). I have tried setting the `contentMode` to preserve the image's aspect ratio, but when I run my app, the image is always distorted.

I tried setting the `UIView`'s content mode to both `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` in turn. In both cases, the photo is still distorted in the same way. I also tried, just for kicks, `UIContentModeLeft`, which also resulted in the same distort presentation. My understanding is that these 3 modes should have presented very different images.

I've done a `ctrl-f` through the view controller code, but there is only once occurrence of `contentMode` and it is where I am setting the property. Are there other properties I should look at that could be interfering?

Here is the code that sets up the image view and accompanying image. This is the only code in the whole project that refers to the image view. Also I am not using any sort of auto layout features, though I don't see why that should affect aspect ratio and content mode anyhow.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.height*.11, self.width, self.height*.55)];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSLog(@"Image height and width are %f and %f", self.imageView.image.size.height, self.imageView.image.size.width);
NSLog(@"imageview height and width are %f and %f", self.imageView.frame.size.height, self.imageView.frame.size.width);

[self.view addSubview: self.imageView];
```

Why doesn't the `contentMode` affect how my image is displayed, and how can I fix this? Ultimately I want to use the scale aspect fill option so there is no empty space within the image view but so that the aspect is also preserved.

Comment: @matt It is not an outlet, the entire app is programmatic, you can see on the 3rd line of my code where self.imageView is allocated and initialized.

Comment: @matt I know because I know what the original data looks like since I provided it from my web server. I also know because I tried out SpaceDog's solution below, which proves my data isn't distorted.

Comment: I should have stuck to my guns... :) You allocate and initialize it in the 3rd line of code but I was asking about the 2nd line of code.

Comment: @matt ah ha, makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

EDIT

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,      self.height*.11, self.width, self.height*.55)];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 NSLog(@"Image height and width are %f and %f",    self.imageView.image.size.height, self.imageView.image.size.width);
NSLog(@"imageview height and width are %f and %f", self.imageView.frame.size.height, self.imageView.frame.size.width);

[self.view addSubview: self.imageView];
```

Set the content mode after u allocate the imageview

Comment: if you read my question I specify that I have tried that content mode. It shows no effect. The whole problem is that setting my contentMode, regardless of what I set it to, seems to show no effect.

Comment: Check the Edit!! found the issue